# Adding a footer to my Enterprise Wiki aspx page layout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, publishing-site, page-layout

I am implementing a Publishing site that uses Enterprise Wiki template. The current page layout I am using is the `EnterpriseWiki.aspx` page layout. but I need to add a footer for all the Wiki pages including some copy right info. so is there a way to edit the page .aspx page layout and add a footer to it.
BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would presume that its not in the aspx but rather in the masterpage! its easily done in sharepoint desinger! or through code in a text editor like notepad++ ect....

doing it in the masterpage will do it for all! if you do it within the layouts it would be within the body! and would look wrong ;)! Layouts aspx is for the body thats defined in the masterpage, the masterpage contains all (headder, body and footer).

As stated if you do it in the layouts aspx it will be in the body at the bottom but within the middle of the page as there are other placeholders below the body tag and will look auful ;) doing it in the master page will enable you to have it outside of the body tag and within the footer, this inturn will also display in all pages! if you dont want it in all pages than you can create another masterpage that you can set to that page that doesnt contain the footer but from what im guessing you want it in all the pages for consistancy :)

what im trying to get to is that, when you create any website in html asp.net or other you dont put in a footer menu or copyright in the bottom of the body :) but rather just below it, the body is for content! in sharepoint terms webparts list/librarys ect, the layouts aspx is a meer content placeholder for webparts (webpart zones) or zones for anything else like library, lists ect. think of it like a table (layout) where the content will reside

even tho its for 2010 its applicable for 2013 and 2007

http://elledmytryszyn.com/2013/01/28/create-custom-footer-using-sharepoint-2010-master-page/